# Integrating Leadbolt ads in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ads, leadbolt

I'm trying to integrate notification ads from Leadbolt in my iPhone app.I downloaded the Leadbolt iPhone SDK and followed the instructions given in their pdf.

As i am trying to load notification ads, i added the following code in the app delegate class..

```
static LeadboltOverlay *myAdController;
myAdController = [[LeadboltOverlay alloc] init]; 
[myAdController setSectionId:@”YOUR_SECTION_ID”]; 
[myAdController loadNotification];
```

I get the following error in the 3rd line(setSectionId method).

```
 Instance method setSectionId not found
```

Checked out their header file and found that it has been declared as a static method.But in their documentation they are calling it as an instance method.

I'm confused and dont have a clue as to how  to proceed now.

I mailed their support team but they havent given me any proper solutions.
I'm sure some of u might have faced the same problem while integrating the Leadbolt SDK.Kindly provide solution for this issue..

Help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What you have posted looks correct so I am not sure why you are experiencing issues. I would try again and if you do experience further issues please re-contact the support team quoting tiket id: OCI-460673. LeadBolt Support

Comment: @LeadBoltTechSupport- i am facing the same problem as mentioned by Mr.Anonymous. Any solution?

Comment: @LeadBoltTechSupport, I am facing the same problem. Any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that `setSectionId` has been declared as static method then you can not access it with an instance for sure.

you can access it only by its class, try

`[LeadboltOverlay setSectionId:@"YOUR ID"];` instead of your

```
[myAdController setSectionId:@”YOUR_SECTION_ID”];
```

It should work.
`